# How to check if device has fingerprint hardware/sensor and fingerprint is enabled or not in android using BiometricManager

Tags: android, kotlin, fingerprint, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

I want to integrate Biometric detection in my app. I want to check 2 condition before show the BiometricPromt authentication to the user:

1. Detect the Biometric sensor/hardware available or not in the device.
2. Detect any Biometric is enrolled or not in the device.

Have tried lots of SO answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57727545/how-to-check-biometric-hardware-is-available-using-biometricmanager-or-biometric?rq=3) but didn't solve my requirement. Whenever am trying to check for hardware using below method every time used to get BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED status and even for checking the fingerprint enrolled or not getting the same status BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED.

Is there any way to detect biometric hardware presence and user enrolment in the device there will get the respective status based on condition like BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED and BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE?
And will get the accurate status?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you and is what you are looking for.

```
val biometricManager = BiometricManager.from(this)
when (biometricManager.canAuthenticate(BIOMETRIC_STRONG or DEVICE_CREDENTIAL)) {
BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS ->
    Log.d("MY_APP_TAG", "App can authenticate using biometrics.")
BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE ->
    Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "No biometric features available on this device.")
BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE ->
    Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "Biometric features are currently unavailable.")
BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED -> {
    // Prompts the user to create credentials that your app accepts.
    val enrollIntent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_BIOMETRIC_ENROLL).apply {
        putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_BIOMETRIC_AUTHENTICATORS_ALLOWED,
            BIOMETRIC_STRONG or DEVICE_CREDENTIAL)
    }
    startActivityForResult(enrollIntent, REQUEST_CODE)
    }
}
```

In the when condition you get the biometric success, error with the hardware, any enrolled or biometric allowed or not in the device.

For more clearance please refer [here](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth)

Comment: Yeah even have tried above solution also but if hardware is not present then getting below condition as True:
BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED not this one BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE

Comment: Strange, this must be the device specific behaviour else this will not happening on all the devices.

Although i found something which may helpful to you please refer this question :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968732/determine-if-biometric-hardware-is-present-and-the-user-has-enrolled-biometrics

Comment: Yes even am also surprised why am getting same status for different condition. have checked in emulators as don't have mobile in which fingerprint sensor is disabled.

Comment: Okay strange, but for surety must check with device as well which don't have the Biometric..